# How can I apply dynamic number formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I've programmed an Excel document for my cryptocurrency portfolio. I add new currencies in a table, to which I pull data via an API to get the prices. I format the result like this: #.##0,00000000 [$ETH] (for Ethereum).

What I would like to achieve is, that when I input currency in column A, the value in column B is formatted to this currency.

Example: http://prntscr.com/p3sof8

So if I input XRP in A5, the value in B5 would read 0,00000000 XRP.
There's no fixed number of currencies I'd use, since I may add new every day.

Basic version of the above logic would be:

Input currency from column A into formatting argument like: #.##0,00000000 [$], except for BTC where the format would be: ฿0,00000000
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in your Sheet e.g "Sheet1"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Count = 1 Then
            If .Column = 1 Then
                If .Value <> "BTC" Then
                    .Offset(, 1).NumberFormat = "0.00000000" & """ " & .Value & """"
                Else
                    .Offset(, 1).NumberFormat = """" & ChrW(&HE3F) & """" & "0.00000000"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems to work, but it moves the decimal. I'm no VBA pro, tried to edit a bit but it didn't work: http://prntscr.com/p4kwix 

Is it possible to have 0,00000000 - so 8 decimals always? Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer, seems like it used the thousand separator as the decimal point  before, so I removed that. Also I added a condition that stops it if more than one cell is edited at the same time, since it will cause an error if you do.

Comment: Another question: can i "tie" the expression to only one table? As I'd need this feature for example on Table1 for column 3, on Table2 on column 5, etc?

Comment: @KGx Probably but "Another question:" should be posted as another question. Here's a couple of questions you can answer in your upcoming question: Do you have multiple tables on the same sheet or are they located in different sheets? Do they all have the same starting column? Should the offset be constant? And also try adding some code and maybe a more explanatory picture

Comment: Ok, thank you - I'll open another question and include the suggested.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use VBA. You can do this with conditional formatting.

To do the specific example:

1. Go to cell B5
2. Click `Conditional Formatting` > `New Rule...`
3. Select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
4. As the formula, put `=$A$5="XRP"`
5. Click Format and on the Number tab, set it to custom such as `#.##0,00000000 [$XRP]`

I will leave it up to you to generalize this

Comment: Thank you - I tried that already, but since I use many different currencies, the conditional formatting looks quite messy